# CyanogenMod 12 - is there quick sound/vibrate switch

Tags: cyanogenmod

In CM 11 there was a switch to mute my phone or put it on vibrate. I can't seem to find it in CM12. There are only profiles, which are not what I would like to have. Is this something missing from Android 5.0 Lollipop and thus not present in CM12, or did CM "broke" something? Or am I blind and couldn't find it, but it's there?

Comment: Do you mean the option in Quick Notification Settings?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I would like to be able to choose between normal (ringer + vibration), vibration only, silent (no sound + no vibration).

Answer (score 0):

You are right, no quick switch from top of the screen.

- Solution 1: long press Power button, you get the option to switch to vibrate
- Solution 2: change volume with physicals buttons, tap on setup on the right side of the sound pane. You will find options to switch to vibrate or mute for a given time or definitively.